# Failed processing manifest / Add fileprovider

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have a .NET7 Maui Application and try to add an provider to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I Always get errors when building the project.

`APT2067 failed processing manifest.`

`APT2260 resource xml/provider_paths (aka MyApp:xml/provider_paths) not found.`

How can I solve the problem?

Tried to change build actions of MyApp\Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\provider_paths.xml to AndroidResource, but don't have AndroidResource it as option in my project.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried to change build actions of
> MyApp\Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\provider_paths.xml to
> AndroidResource, but don't have AndroidResource it as option in my
> project.

It's weird. I create the provider_paths.xml in the folder named xml below the values folder in the android part. Build Action of the provider_paths.xml default is `AndroidResource` at the beginning:

[image]

Try this: close VS, delete obj and bin file, reopen the project by VS and see if Build Action has AndroidResource.

**Upadate**

Note that the version of VS, and this issue: [There is no AndroidResource build action in Maui](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1500).

Comment: I'm unsure about the reason behind this. I've noticed a limited number of items in the Build Action combobox and it doesn't change when restarting VS or cleaning solution.

Comment: What's the version of your VS? And see this issue: [There is no AndroidResource build action in Maui](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1500).

Comment: Thank you - okay i see the point. Then it's a VS bug.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have the possibility to change my build action to `AndroidResource`.

[Screenshot Build Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRfxk.png)

But I found a workaround / solution for me, that works:

I manually added `AndroidResource` to my `MyApp.csproj`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidResource Include="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\provider_paths.xml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </AndroidResource>
</ItemGroup>
```